# Probability bound that the sum of random variables with positive mean is not positive

Tags: probability-inequalities

**EDIT**: The distribution I gave below is not necessarily correct for $n > 1$, so the bound I gave below does not hold.

---

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables from a distribution with positive mean and range between $a$ and $b$. Let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

We know that

$$\Pr\left(\bar{X} \leq 0\right) = \Pr\left(\bar{X} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] \leq -\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]\right)$$

Using Hoeffding's inequality, we have that
$$\Pr\left(\bar{X} \leq 0\right) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{2n\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]^2}{(b - a)^2}\right)$$

However, I'm convinced that the distribution that maximizes $\Pr\left(\bar{X} \leq 0\right)$ subject to the constraint that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = \mu$ for some fixed $0 < \mu \leq b$ is one that puts as much mass as possible on $0$, while maintaining that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = \mu$. I believe one can show that this distribution is one that puts $\frac{\mu}{b}$ probaility on $b$ and $1 - \frac{\mu}{b}$ probability on $0$.

Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables from the simple distribution described above and let $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$. We thus get that

$$\Pr\left(\bar{X} \leq 0\right) \leq \Pr\left(\bar{Y} \leq 0\right) = \Pr\left(Y_1 = 0, \dots, Y_n = 0\right) = \left(1 - \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{b}\right)^n$$

This is much tighter than the bound obtained using Hoeffding's inequality. It doesn't even depend on $a$ and the dependency on $b$ is much better. Am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find this bound mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I saw something similar in a Coursera course from the École
Polytechnique with the lecturer showing $\mathbb{P}(X - \mathbb{E}[X] \ge r) \le e^{-2r^2/\text{Osc}
(X)^2}$ where $\text{Osc}(X)$ is the width of the range of $X$, and I came to a similar conclusion that $\mathbb{P}(X - \mathbb{E}[X] \ge r) \le 1 - \frac{r}{\text{Osc}(X)}$ when $0 \lt r \lt \text{Osc}(X)$ would be simpler to demonstrate and a sharper bound.  I think in your case the example was not so much aiming a providing the best answer to the exact question but  demonstrating the use of Hoeffding's inequality.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! But does this suggest we could get a bound that is much tighter than Hoeffding's inequality in general, at least in some cases? I haven't thought through your example, but it seems like in some cases we can do much better than Hoeffding's inequality depending on what the value of $t$ (or $r$ in your example) is.

Comment: @Henry The distribution I gave is not necessarily the one that maximizes the probability when $n > 1$. One wants to put probability mass on negative values in that case since they can offset positive ones. So the bound does not hold!